# Is there a way to add float variable to exisitng flat row?

Tags: python, sqlite

Working on cash app and I need to configure db to add funds to existing amount. In my opinion my code is logical and doesn't show any error just do not update the row (still 0). When I mention the question like SET cash=cash+50  it works.. But in this case I need data imported from variable. Thanks for advance.

```
def deposit_cash(login, amount):
    con = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("UPDATE users SET cash=cash+? WHERE login=?", (amount,login,))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't directly comment, but is it the case that you're passing your arguments in reverse?
In the function definition you have it set as `login, amount` and then in the execute statement you have `amount,login`. Are you possibly calling the function with the arguments in the reversed location?

Comment: Yeah, that helped ! I thought it had no impact, but still.. Thanks a lot :)